# Unexpected behavior in Python's set.issubset

Tags: python

I have the following code

```py
(Pdb) set(range(2, 2)).issubset(set(range(10, 95)))
True
```

and I don't understand why it's returning `True`. `issubset` is supposed to check if a set contains all the items of another set, but `2` can't be contained in a range from `10` to `95`.

Am I misunderstanding Python's doc? Or is that a bug?

Comment: `set(range(2, 2))` returns a empty set, not a set containing `2`

Answer (score 2):

a = set(range(2,2)) is returning empty set

[image]

Since, set "a" has nothing to compare in set "b" therefore it is returning True.